# AnalyticsReceiver in Google Analytics Tracking

Tags: android, google-analytics-api, android-broadcastreceiver

In Google Analytics Tracking Ver1, it has class `AnalyticsReceiver`.

But when I used Google Analytics Tracking Ver2, it hasn't got `AnalyticsReceiver` class. I don't know which class should I use instead.

In manifest declared when use Google Analytics Tracking:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.AnalyticsReceiver"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Can you help me.

Answer (score 4):

Google seems to move this class with every release. Depending on your Google Analytics SDK version, the value for `android:name` will change. Here's all of the various versions for anyone else upgrading beyond v2.

Google Analytics SDK v2: `com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver`

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Google Analytics SDK v3: `com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver`

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Google Analytics SDK v4: `com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver`

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Is it ok to use android:exported="false" for AnalyticsReceiver?  I get a warning "Exported receiver does not require permission" if "exported" is not set or set to true.

Comment: Seems that for all of these, the IDE complains that this class doesn't exist. I use `implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.1'` . What should I do instead? Needs migration of some sort from v1.1.2 ?