# Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver

Tags: android, google-analytics, crash, classnotfoundexception

I have uploaded the Android app into playstore. While downloading it for the first time it gets crashed but after that it works fine. Its showing the error as **Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver** **Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"** .

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you manage to resolve it, or do you have any follow-up on it?

Comment: No ihave not found any solutions for it

Comment: Exactly same issue, did anyone find the solution?

Answer (score 5):

I believe that issue related to your manifest file and refer to **INSTALL_REFERRER**.

Make sure if **AnalyticsReceiver** class included to your app

My suggestion, if you not use that receiver you can remove it, otherwise will keep throw crash error

Note:
As far as I know **com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver** from Google Analytics SDK v3
While if you using Google Analytics SDK v4 you should use **com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver**

Please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24194514/1578100) too

Comment: My friend, thank you for your response! It saved me hours of testing. Thank you very much!!!